# golang goroutine synchronization expected behaviour

Tags: go

The following piece of code try to send to the channel on the main goroutine and receive from another goroutine but a few times it returns as expected but a few times it exits without printing any on the console screen

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        data := <-ch
        fmt.Printf("Received: %t", data)
    }()
    ch <- true
}
```

At the same time, the following piece of code works as expected everytime, one difference is that an additional check has been added to check if the channel is closed or not which always throws the same expected output.
Does this ensure that a check on the channel is a must than optional ? or anything wrong with the code

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        data, ok := <-ch
        if !ok {
            fmt.Println("Channel closed")
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("Received: %t", data)
    }()
    ch <- true
}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the print statement in your goroutine will have time executing by the time `main` finishes. Check out https://go.dev/ref/mem and also `sync.WaitGroup`.

Comment: @jub0bs ok, but the second piece of code prints Received: true everytime

Comment: @cslrnr: *"but the second piece of code prints Received: true everytime"* --  does it though? https://imgur.com/a/1XrRrwK (no it does not).

Comment: @mkopriva I re-ran the code again, this time i see the program exited a couple of times out of 10. jub0bs i got it thanks,  https://imgur.com/dNUzi9g

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for goroutine to complete before main routine exit.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan bool)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        data := <-ch
        fmt.Printf("Received: %t", data)
    }()
    ch <- true
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The thing is your second piece of code doesn't print Received: true every time. I tested it several times.

As @jub0bs mentioned there is no guarantee that your goroutine finishes before the main routine. You must control it yourself.